# Laravel 8: How to seed a pivot table in many to many relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-seeding

I want to seed my tables via seeder/factory.
I want to seed a Pivot table, which connects the tables `atg` and `debtor` and is called `atg_debtor`, which hast an `id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `atg_id`, `debtor_id`.

When inserting data via Eloquent everything works fine. When I try to seed my db with Seeders/Factory it always tries to insert data to my `atg` table, which I don´t want. I want to seed the `debtor` table (that works fine) and the pivot table with a given `atg_id` and the dynamic `debtor_id`, which is created whilst seeding the debtor.

My Debtor Model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Atg;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class Debtor extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function atg()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Atg::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

The DebtorSeeder:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use App\Models\Atg;
use App\Models\Debtor;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DebtorSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $debitor = Debtor::factory()
                ->count(1)
                ->hasAtg(1)
                ->create();
    }
}
```

The DebtorFactory:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Debtor;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class DebtorFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Debtor::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'created_at' => now(),
            'created_by_id' => '3',
            'rechtsform' => 'Unternehmen',
            'name' => $this->faker->company    
        ];
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so first you can check if in the database there is `Atg`, if no you can seed like you do, otherwise you can seed `Debtor` then save `Atg` in relations(`->atg()` is your relation name so improve it if i wrote wrong name) like so:

P.S. Also i removed `->count(1)` from `Debtor` because by default it creates one item.

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use App\Models\Atg;
use App\Models\Debtor;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DebtorSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $atg = Atg::first();
        if($atg){
           $debitor = Debtor::factory()
                ->create();

           $debitor->atg()->save($atg);
        }else {
           $debitor = Debtor::factory()
                ->hasAtg(1)
                ->create();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That works for 1 insert very well. If I want to seed f/e 10 with ->count(10) than it doesn´t work anymore. Can you please explain how to seed more than 1 debtor? Error: BadMethodCallException Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::atg does not exist.

Comment: I took your code, which worked fine (thank you again), and added before ->create(); ->count(10). Then it throws the posted error

Comment: Okay, i understand the problem, so in that case it will return you a  Collection instance, not Model instance, so if you want to insert many you need to do like this
Sorry for bad formatting

`$debitors = Debtor::factory()
                ->count(10)
                ->create();
           foreach($debitors as $debitor){
                $debitor->atg()->save($atg);
           }`

Comment: Hi Miqayel, I guess it would. I achieved it with a while loop: if($atg){
            while($i < 10l) {
                $debitor = Debtor::factory()
                    ->hasAdresse(1)
                    ->create();
                $debitor->atg()->save($atg);
                $i++;
            }
        } thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're seeding your database tables separately:

```
// Seed 50 Atg records
Atg::factory(50)->create();

// Seed 4 Debtor records
Debtor::factory(4)->create();
```

You could override the `configure` method in your `Debtor` factory to attach some `Atg` models once they have been created:

```
class DebtorFactory extends Factory
{
    public function configure()
    {
        return $this->afterCreating(function (Debtor $debtor) {
            // Once a Debtor record has been created
            // Pick between 1 and 5 Atg records in a random order
            // Associate the Atg and Debtor records
            $debtor->atg()
                   ->attach(Atg::inRandomOrder()->take(random_int(1, 5))->pluck('id'));
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: In your afterCreating function, you can also call the factory and assign the debtor id

Answer (score 0):

You can use `hasAttached` method to seed pivot table in Laravel 8
In your DatabaseSeeder class file.

```
Atg::factory()->hasAttached(
               Debtor::factory();
              )
              ->create();
```

That will help you each Atg create item with dynamic Debtor id in `atg_debtor` table. But it needs to connect in the model class binding.

```
class Debtor extends Model
{
  use HasFactory;
    
   public function atg()
   {
      return $this->belongsToMany(Atg::class)->withTimestamps();
   }
 }
```

Other Methods,
You can use Using Magic Methods to create seed data in Pivot Table

```
Atg::factory()->hasDebtor(1)
              ->create();
```

Here are the reference methods
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#pivot-table-attributes

Comment: upon running the seed we get ```Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::getConnectionName()```